# Receive invalid_grant from Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I have a problem to send api to Exchange Server.
I registered an app in Azure and added the "Office 365 Exchange Online" permissions into the api access role.

Next, I followed this [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/) to get an app-only access token, and then sent GetItem EWS api to get an mail, but the server responses error with 401 Unauthorized.

`x-ms-diagnostics: 2000008;"reason"=The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.";error_category="invalid_grant"`

Is there permission settings in Office 365 I have to set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I use JWT tool to see my access token, I found that the token doesn't have "Office 365 Exchange Online" permissions.

The root cause is that while I was authorizing the app to use my Office 365 account , I haven't set "Office 365 Exchange Online" permissions to my app.

Even thought I edited the permission setting soon after, the token is still no permission.

Therefore, after modifying permission setting, we should re-auth and get a new app-only access token.

Comment: can you please elaborate more this: " re-auth and get a new app-only access token." I did not get this properly.

Comment: @always-a-learner It means that you have to get a new tenent_id. The old one only has old permissions.

Comment: @JudithTing "After I use JWT tool to see my access token, I found that the token doesn't have "Office 365 Exchange Online" permissions" how do you figure this by looking at the JWT tool? I am seeing similar error and want to find out what I should be looking for. Also, how do you set Office 365 Exchange Online permission to the app?